# app crashes when i change the order of my XML RelativeLayout android

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, z-index

The title says it all, my app keeps crashing everytime i change the layout view, i need the button to be on the very top and the imageView1 to be at the very bottom, with iv_photo being in between them two. So i try to take my xml button and move it to the bottom, and my app crashes, im not changing the code or anything, all im simply doing is moving code around. heres my code

DOESNT CRASH

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_crop"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:text="@string/Nothing" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/whitestrip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

DOES CRASH

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/whitestrip" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_crop"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:text="@string/Nothing" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Heres the errors i get in the LogCat

```
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.atmebeta/com.example.atmebeta.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at com.example.atmebeta.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:106)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-01 13:49:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(32148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have seen stuff like this before.

Try running a clean build and then run your app again.

on the window bar go to "Project" -> "clean"

clean all solutions and then it should be all good.

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks a million my friend. So stupid we have to do that though.. really google?!? lol...